# I have to perform togling for single UIButton which I have generated from loop for different frame

Tags: ios, loops, uibutton, toggle

In my iOS application, I have to change image as per button click.
 I have to perform togling for single  UIButton which I have generated from loop for different frame

It is working fine if I perform action on single button, if I have performing action for multiple button the image is not properly changing as per button action

Here is my button

```
btnFullScreen = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [btnFullScreen setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnFullScreen setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-30,8,16,14)];
    [btnFullScreen setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [btnFullScreen addTarget:self action:@selector(showPopUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnFullScreen.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:btnFullScreen];
```

Here is my  button action code

```
-(void)showPopUp:(id)sender{
if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setSelected:NO];
}else {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
[self.parent.parent addPopOversExcept:self.parent];
```

}

Thanks

Comment: How is 'sender' linked to the button you have clicked on ?

Comment: if you already setting the images for two different state why are you calling showPopUp method?

Comment: Updated my method,actually calling some another method from button action

Comment: But my images are not changing as I am setting the same

Comment: how many buttons are there in your view now?

Comment: Now its 3 but it will change depends upon data count.. it would be 5 , 6 7 etc

Comment: Your question does not provide much information about your actual requirement/problem. Please provide little more brief explanation or pictorial view.

Answer (score 0):

I had done this before in one of my app.
I was creating button in each tableview cell.

So,Take this code as `Reference`.

1.Specific Method.

```
- (void)methodName:(UIButton *)sender
 {
int i = [sender.titleLabel.text intValue];
NSNumber *numb;
if(i == 0)
{
    numb = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    sender.titleLabel.text = @"1";
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
else
{
    numb = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    sender.titleLabel.text = @"0";
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
}
```

2.Setting UIButton Programatically in UITabelview viewForHeaderInSection.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 20, 30, 30)];

[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(methodName:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
button.tag = section;
if([[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue])
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.titleLabel.text = @"0";
}
else
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.titleLabel.text = @"1";
}
```